# For $0 \leq f \in L^1([a,b])$ if $\int_a^x (f-F') (u)du \geq 0$ then $f-F'\geq 0$ a.e.

Tags: real-analysis

In a proof I've encountered, there's the following claim:

> Since $\int_a^x (f-F') (u)du \geq 0$ then $f-F'\geq 0$ a.e.

for $0 \leq f \in L^1([a,b])$.

I cannot see how to prove this transition. I thought of using something similar to Royden's proof for the following lemma applied to $f-F'$ and with "$\geq 0$" instead of "$=0$".

[image]

My questions are:

1. Regardless of my specific setup, am I correct that Royden's proof would hold for $\geq 0$ the same way it holds for $=0$? (I sense I might be missing where this breaks, since it seems like a strong claim).
2. If indeed Royden's proof holds for $\geq 0$, then why would $f-F' \in L^1$? (I can claim that $F$ is measurable since the integral is a continuous function, but why would $\int |F'| < \infty$?)
3. If none of the above proves the claim, how else might I go about proving this?